# Reset Kid's Corner due to broken links causing 80070003 error

Tags: kids-corner

I have several broken links in the kid's corner, possibly due to the update from 8.0 to 8.1 on my AtivS. I can't remove the broken links, as the customization page shows no selected videos or pictures, but the entries are still present on the kid's corner page. As the selected entries resided on my SD card I tried to remove the links by formatting, removing and reinserting the card but the links are still there.

Is there any possibility to perform a full reset of the kid's corner ?

Comment: What happens when you disable then re-enable it in Settings ?

Comment: It simply disables the kids corner. When clicking on the app icon the page to enable it is shown. But all previous setting are still existing. There seems to be no way of putting it in its initial state...

Comment: A reset of your phone might be the only option?

Comment: That's quite ridiculous for such a problem...

Comment: True, but it sounds a like a bug in the upgrade process and I'm sure aware of any other way to reset Kid's Corner.